# hi i am having an issue to update related data

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to add a member to a group in my application, I need be able to add one or more members to a group. Please can you assist?

below are my classes

```
public class member
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int memberid { get; set;}

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="first name")]

    public string membername { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "last name")]

    public string memberlastname { get; set;}

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "email address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string email { get; set; }

    public int groupid { get; set; }

    public virtual group groups { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int groupid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "group name")]
    public string groupname { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<member> members { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should also show your code where you are trying to add (and save) your new group member.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to change the data type of your `group.members` property from an `IEnumerable<member>` to a `List<member>`:
    public class group
    {
        // Other properties not shown
        public List members { get; set; }
    }

Then you could just call the `Add` method:

```
static void Main()
{
    group g = new group();
    member m = new member();
    g.members.Add(m);
```